# Cannot find WebDriverWait class in OpenQa Selenium 3.7

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've just started a new project in Selenium with Webdriver 3.7 and I was looking for the Webdriverwait class in the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace where I remeber it being, however I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I installed Selenium on my VS 2017 using the NuGet manager and installed both Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support packages.

I have also put the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace in the code with the using keyword.

I'm sure it must be something obvious that I'm missing, but it's driving me crazy.

does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: After trying to figure this out a bit more I've found that I only have access to part of the classes available in the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace. There are three classes and two interface defined in that namespace that I cannot seem to access, these are: DefaultWait, SystemClock, WebDriverWait, IClock and IWait.

So it can't be a problem with there not being a reference to the OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI namespace, since the rest of the classes in there I can access just fine.

Comment: Where are you `was looking`? What are you looking for? Documentation?

Comment: No, I'm looking for the class. I literally cannot define an object of the type WebDriverWait. I'm wondering it they changed its name or moved it to a different namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Documentation **`WebdriverWait`** class is in **`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`** namespace only.

### Inheritance Hierarchy :

1. **`System.Object`**
2. **`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait<IWebDriver>`**
3. **`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait`**

---

> **Namespace** : **`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI`**

---

> **Assembly** : **`WebDriver.Support (in WebDriver.Support.dll) Version: 3.1.0`**

---

### Snapshot :

[image: WebDriverWait]

---

### Snapshot :

[image: OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI Namespace]

---

### Update :

As you are still unable to access the classes I would suggest to uninstall & again install the **`Selenium.Webdriver`** and **`Selenium.Support`** packages.

Comment: Yes, I know. I read the documentation, however that still does not solve my problem.

Like I said. I have OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI and Selenium.Support package referenced, however I still can't create an object of type WebDriverWait and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @Vladimirlazar Check out my updated  Answer. Let me know the status.

Comment: Uninstalling Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support packages and than reinstalling them seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling Slenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support worked for me. Thanks a lot!