# The name 'PageFactory' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, selenium, page-factory

I'm creating a test automation framework in c#. At the top of the project I have "using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;", however when I try to reference PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageName) I'm seeing the message "The name 'PageFactory' does not exist in the current context".

I thought the PageFactory class was included as part of the Selenium.Support nu get package. Tutorials online seem to reference the PageFactory in the same way I am with no extra imports, is there anything I'm missing?

NuGet packages:

Using Selenium.WebDriver version 3.9.1

Using Selenium.Support version 3.9.1

Using NUnit 3.9.0

Using NUnit3TestAdapter 3.9.0

Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.5.0

Code below:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Framework.TestCases
{
    class TestCase
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            String pathToDrivers = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\Drivers";
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(pathToDrivers);
            String searchTerm = "Search Term";

            driver.Url = "https://website.com/";
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, homePage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually just created a new project, and ported everything over with one difference, the type of project I created was a Visual C# > Test > Unit Test Project, before the project I had created was Visual C# > .Net Core > Class Library project (I was following a tutorial).

I'm not too sure if this changed anything as such or just meant I had a clear project when I re downloaded and installed the NuGet packages, however I can now access the PageFactory class and associated methods. Thanks to everyone who replied.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone else comes across this question, reason why you can't find the PageFactory nowadays is pretty simple: **It does not exist**.

Namely, with 3.11.0 release of Selenium.Support, **PageFactory** and **ExpectedConditions** were marked as obsolete. 
With Selenium.Support 3.12.0 they have been removed completely. More on that topic [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2018/03/deprecating-parts-of-seleniums-net.html).

Solution to this is to simply add **DotNetSeleniumExtras** to your packages as those were moved to separate [repository](https://github.com/DotNetSeleniumTools/DotNetSeleniumExtras). One can also find useful Dreamescaper's [fork](https://github.com/Dreamescaper/DotNetSeleniumExtras/) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core)) that has added .NET Core support until the original repo finds an owner.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone faces the same issue, please install from NuGet package manager the following:
`DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core (3.12.0)`

Comment: After adding `DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core` you can use `PageFactory.InitElement(driver, this)` by importing `using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;`

Answer (score 2):

small update for all people who have the same problem.

: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4387

> " *Further discussion on this issue will not change the decision on the removal of the .NET PageFactory implementation* "

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, tried to uninstall and re-install but it did not work. Then I went looking for NuGet packages with Selenium in the name and found that the Selenium.Support package is separate from the main Selenium.Webdriver package. So if you're having this issue, go back and make sure you've installed both Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support packages through Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

PageFactory is still available

Reference packages

```
<PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects" Version="3.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core" Version="3.12.0" />
```

Then

```cs
using SeleniumExtras.PageObjects;

 HomePage loginPage = new HomePage(driver);
 PageFactory.InitElements(driver, HomePage)
```

`PageFactory.InitElements` is void.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that when you _try to reference `PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageName)`, you are seeing an error message as follows :

```
The name 'PageFactory' does not exist in the current context".
```

If you look at the API Documentation of [*PageFactory Class*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_PageObjects_PageFactory.htm) it clearly mentions the following :

- System.Object : **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.PageFactory**
- Namespace : **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects**

So the error essentially means that there are some issues with the installation of the **`Selenium.Support.PageObjects`** package.

### Solution

A proper solution would be to completely *Uninstall* the **`Selenium.WebDriver`** and **`Selenium.Support.PageObjects`** related packages and then reinstalling them back through the *NuGet Manager* .

> Note : You can find a similar [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430369/cannot-find-webdriverwait-class-in-openqa-selenium-3-7/47431694#47431694).

---

### Update

As you are still seeing the same error can you make a small change in your code as follows :

Replace :

```
HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, homePage);
```

With :

```
HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage);
```

Comment: I've uninstalled both Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support as suggested and re-added them but no joy.

Comment: Can you update the question with the _Selenium_ , _WebDriver_ and other _binary_ version info?

Comment: Updated question with nuget packages and versions installed.

Comment: I've tried with the updated solution of HomePage homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, HomePage); and it still seems to present the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install from NuGet package:
   **DotNetSeleniumExtras.PageObjects.Core**
2. You can use **PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);**