# The type or namespace SelectElement could not be found in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunittestadapter

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputUsername")).SendKeys("aca");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("inputPassword")).SendKeys("123");
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("button")).Click();

SelectElement oSelect = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("selectFilterbyUser")));
oSelect.selectByText("Alex");
```

Do anyone have solution for the problem that i had attach in the above? Try to use `SelectElement` but it displays:

```
The type or namespace `SelectElement` could not be found.
```

I tried to see the potential fixes, but it shows only three options which are

- Generate class `SelectElement` in a new file
- Generate class `SelectElement`
- Generate nested class `SelectElement`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's better to include the text of your error in the question rather than as an image. You will also need to include the relevant portion of your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Kevin avoid posting the image link and share your code on the question with proper format. You can refer this link [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, try right-clicking on `SelectElement` and then `resolve namespace` click on correct namespace, so it will add it at the top of the file

Comment: @Rafalon it didn't show any namespace there. it only show this three( Generate class SelectElement in a new file, generate class SelectElement and generate nested class SelectElement) when right click

Comment: @Kevin Show the "using" import lines on the top of your code. The issue is probably there

Comment: using NUnit.Framework;

using OpenQA.Selenium;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

Comment: Do you have any error on one of these lines? Like maybe you don't have the references included in your project?

Comment: @Rafalon no error the only thing is using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI; greyed out

Comment: the answer from @BHOW is the only one to solve the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Referring to a few previous posts it seems if you are using frameworks like ***nunittestadapter***, ***NUnit.Framework***, ***VS 2017 using the NuGet Manager*** sometimes there can be issues with the installation /configuration.

### SelectElement Class

As per the documentation the [**`SelectElement`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm) Class is pretty much available within [**`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI Namespace`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI.htm) which provides a convenience method for manipulating selections of options in an HTML select element.

---

> Inheritance Hierarchy

```
System.Object
    OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement
```

---

> Namespace: **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI**

---

> Assembly: **WebDriver.Support (in WebDriver.Support.dll) Version: 3.1.0**

---

> Syntax: **public class SelectElement : IWrapsElement**

---

Snapshot:

[image: selectelement_class]

### Solution

Uninstall & reinstall the Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support packages, that will surely fix the problem.

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in [**Cannot find WebDriverWait class in OpenQa Selenium 3.7**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430369/cannot-find-webdriverwait-class-in-openqa-selenium-3-7/47431694#47431694)

Comment: yes your answer is correct! i reinstall the webdriver support and it is working now!. thanks

Answer (score 13):

You need to make sure to reference the NuGet Package [Selenium.Support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support).

I was having the same issue and then realized that I was only referencing the [Selenium.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) NuGet Package. After adding the Selenium.Support NuGet package, and adding the proper using statements. My SelectElement code successfully compiled.

The proper using statements

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Comment: This is the answer that solves the OP's question as to why SelectElement is not recognized.

Comment: This worked for me, the accepted answer (DebanjanB's) did not.

Comment: what's sneaky is that the selenium.webdriver package has minimal numbers of classes from the support.ui package, enough that you think you have all of it installed. Added that new package as BHOW says and it's good. Sneaky.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium WebDriver C# code for selecting item from Drop Down:

```
IWebElement selectElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("selectFilterbyUser"));
SelectElement oSelect = new SelectElement(selectElement);
```

There are 3 ways to select drop down item:  byText, byIndex, byValue

**1.byText()**

```
oSelect.SelectByText("Alex");
```

**2.byIndex()**

```
SelectAnEducation.SelectByIndex(0);
```

**3.byValue()**

```
SelectAnEducation.SelectByValue("Alex");
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue due to using the pre-release version. v4.00 alpha.  I installed the previous version v3.141.0 and the errors were resolved

[image]

Comment: I did the very same thing, and it didn't work with the newest version of chromedriver. It instead gave me "Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsElement'"

Comment: It's all fun and stuff when installing newest versions until all the documentation and tutorials with SelectElement are obsolete. Much appreciated! Just what I thought about this!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You need to install the proper package from NuGet which is Selenium.Support

Correct using statements is as:

using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Selenium.WebDriver 4.0, one needs to install both Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support nuget packages (same version) to avoid this issue (IWrapsElement / type load exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

In Dotnet 4.7, **SelectElement** is found under **Selenium Support** driver in Nuget Package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).