# The type or namespace name 'IWebDriver' could not be found error while executing Nunit test through Selenium on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create some test cases with selenium on a mac with C#. The IDE I am using is visual studio 2017. I have the following packages installed , selenium web driver, selenium support, selenium firefox web driver. My Question is how do I successfully use selenium to create test cases for website using C#. Whenever I try to run the test cases, the following errors pop up ;

```
/Users/andrew/Projects/test/test/Test.cs(23,23): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Firefox' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenQA.Selenium' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (test)
```

and

```
/Users/andrew/Projects/test/test/Test.cs(9,9): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IWebDriver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (test)
```

Code trial:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
namespace test
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class Test
    {

        IWebDriver driverOne = new FirefoxDriver();

        [Test()]
        public void TestCase()
        {
            driverOne.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to a few previous posts it seems if you are using ***Selenium-WebDriver*** through frameworks like ***Visual Studio 2017***, ***nunittestadapter***, ***NUnit.Framework***, ***VS 2017 using the NuGet Manager*** sometimes there can be issues with the installation /configuration.

### Example: SelectElement Class

As per the documentation the [**`SelectElement`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm) Class is pretty much available within [**`OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI Namespace`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/N_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI.htm) which provides a convenience method for manipulating selections of options in an HTML select element.

---

> Inheritance Hierarchy

```
System.Object
    OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.SelectElement
```

---

> Namespace: **OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI**

---

> Assembly: **WebDriver.Support (in WebDriver.Support.dll) Version: 3.1.0**

---

> Syntax: **public class SelectElement : IWrapsElement**

---

Snapshot:

[image: selectelement_class]

### Solution

Uninstall & reinstall the Selenium.Webdriver and Selenium.Support packages, that will surely fix the problem.

### Reference

You can find relevant discussions in

- [**Cannot find WebDriverWait class in OpenQa Selenium 3.7**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430369/cannot-find-webdriverwait-class-in-openqa-selenium-3-7/47431694#47431694)
- [**The type or namespace SelectElement could not be found in selenium c#**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436557/the-type-or-namespace-selectelement-could-not-be-found-in-selenium-c-sharp/51439593#51439593)

Comment: the build was successful. but now I get this error. TestFixtureSetUp failed in Test

Comment: How do I open a browser with selenium?

Comment: I had to also restart VS after uninstalling the nuget packages and reinstall them again